# js/jQuery - Converting array to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, local-storage

The 2 drop downs I'm using to store into local storage are storing as an array.
How could I convert it where if any arrays are detected then convert it and store it as string instead?

Something like this?

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( value ) === '[object Array]' ) {
  value.toString();
}
```

Please see my fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/137/

Showing being stored as:https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTZ78.jpg

local storage function:

```
save = function () {

        $('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
             var   name = $(this).attr('name');

            if($(this).hasClass('checkers')){
                value = $(this).is(":checked")
                if(value){
                    value='on';
                }else{
                    value='off';
                }
            }

            if(this.name.match(/^multiselect_/)){//removes buggy append
               return false;
            }

            console.log('Saving');
            console.log(name + ':' + value);
            Survey[name] = value;
        });

        if (localStorage.getObj('Surveys') != null) {
            Surveys = localStorage.getObj('Surveys');
        }
         Surveys[$('#FirstName').val() + '.' + $('#LastName').val()] = Survey; //store in big list
        localStorage.setObj('Surveys', Surveys);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var key in this) {
         //console.log(key, this[key]); //log to console
         if($.isArray(this[key])) {
         this[key] = this[key].join(':'); //change array to string separated by :
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to convert an array to a string is array.join(). Called just like that you get a comma-delimited string that contains all of the elements in the array. If you provide a separator (such as array.join('|')) you get a string that is delimited with the separator you provided. Where this fits into your saving function is up to you.

Comment: That was something that I was looking into. How would I go about writing it?

Comment: Now that is a good question indeed. I think you'd need to use Array.isArray for detection and then run the array through the join. To convert back to an array (for the purpose of adding to it easily without string concatenation) you can use string.split(). (I'm still trying to figure out why your dropdown stores as an array instead of just the selected value, but that would probably come easier if I understood your whole project.)

Comment: They are Eric Hynds multiselect widgets if you'd like to look into the documentation. http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Comment: Ah... ok. My guess was multi-select anyway. So, yeah, you should be able to grab the widget output and do an array.join on it to get your values. Might take a little extra code, but it is certainly workable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery.encodeJSON()

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-encodejson

This way you can store your object as a JSON string.

You can then get your object back using the jQuery.parseJSON() function.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it right, i guess this could work:

Use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method and then use JSON.stringify to turn the array into a string.